# Checking if this matrix is Positive Semdefinite?

Tags: matrices, positive-semidefinite

For a matrix $A \in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$ with columns $a_i \in \mathbb R^m$, we know that $A^\top A$ is Positive Semidefinite (PSD).

I am interested in checking if B is positive semidefinite where $B_{ij} = (a_i^\top a_j)^2$. Each component of $B$ is the square of corresponding component of $A^\top A$.

Comment: if $A^\top A$ is diagonal it's obviiously trivial, as a feel I think that you can't conclude nothing in general, but I'm curious to see tha aswers to this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This is a direct consequence of the [Schur product theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_product_theorem): the elementwise product of two positive semidefinite matrices is also positive semidefinite.

Comment: The proof based on eigen decomposition is very illuminating. Thank you!. Was this very obvious to you or did you need to search for this ?

Comment: I had met this fact before, but I had forgotten its name, so it took a small bit of searching to find again.